# Помогите найти ошибку при обмене с сервером

Tags: java, jsoup, jar

Когда запускаю Main-класс на выполнение в Intellij Idea, отправляется запрос на сервер с помощью библиотеки jsoup. Тут же получаю ответ, содержащий нужный класс gs_result_i_t_name.

Тут же генерирую JAR-файл. Запускаю его через Idea (чтобы отслеживать запросы и ответы). Запрос на сервер уходит такой же, как в первом случае. Но ответ совершенно другой. В ответе приходит код, но только в нем уже нет класса gs_result_i_t_name.

В результате работы кода создается файл и в него записываются полученные от сервера данные. При компиляции Main.java файлы заполняются. Но даже если я запускаю JAR-файл отдельно, - результата нет.
В чем может быть дело? Может, каких-то прав не хватает JAR-файлу?

Есть небольшая мысль, что под Idea сервер пропускает запрос, а при выполнении JAR-файла - нет. Все из-за какого-то различия (не знаю какого) между этими запросами. Формат запроса одинаковый в обоих случаях. Может, какой-нибудь User-Agent меняется? Или что-то в этом роде? Хотя я в коде не прописывал User-agent. Сервер, кстати, с HTTPS. Может JSOUP не дружит с ним? Я ведь посылаю логин и пароль.

Вот часть кода, если поможет.
Запрос:

```
Document doc_for = Jsoup.connect(urls + page + i).cookies(loginCookies2).get();
```

Получаю ответ:

```
Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("gs_result_i_t_name");
```

loginCookies2 в первом случае:

```
{bd_login_cookie="1477424432793:7afa7810c87cf2afbff2c39e1de19aa5", JSESSIONID=a2c8e7b6e99b880faade5f3ff23491abe7433171bb650cd.e677e4e7, LASTSRV=tt.ru, landref=""}
```

И во втором:

```
{bd_login_cookie="1477424468318:0ab45a3b6eee5a04ae67b78f5f713d6e", JSESSIONID=802b47ae0ba87e6d220d26c47e3341c3ffadf7e522e3f656.b914f103, LASTSRV=tt.ru, landref=""}
```

Вот скрин настройки Artifacts:
https://goo.gl/vLHPRN

Вот скрин настроек запуска:
https://goo.gl/nbrqXY

Comment: `Тут же генерирую JAR-файл. Запускаю его через Idea`. Поясните процесс запуска конкретнее.

Comment: @post_zeew Пункт меню Run - Edit Configuration... - плюс - Добавляю JAR Application - указываю путь к сгенерированному JAR-файлу